# How can I make 'gulp watch' command work?

Tags: javascript, gulp-watch

Browser console doesn't watch errors but when I try to run the command in git console I have got a error.

```js
let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let watch = require('gulp-watch');
let browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/index.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/index.css'))
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/scss/index.scss', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'src'
        },
        notify: false
    });
});
```

Link to my repository https://github.com/dzhulay/Step-Ham

Comment: Can you please post the errors?

Comment: Error: watching src/scss/index.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
    at Gulp.watch (C:\Step-Ham\node_modules\gulp\index.js:31:11)
    at C:\Step-Ham\gulpfile.js:14:10
    at taskWrapper (C:\Step-Ham\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:415:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\Step-Ham\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

Answer (score 1):

The *[gulp.watch](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch)* function requires a list of files and a **function** as second parameter.

You have to generate the function either with [gulp.parallel](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/parallel) or [gulp.series](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/series), such as in your case:

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/scss/index.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
});
```

Also, in order to avoid the "file exists" error as specified in your comment, please implement "gulp-chmod" in your sass task, such as:

```
var chmod = require('gulp-chmod');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
return gulp.src('src/scss/index.scss')
    .pipe(chmod(0o755))
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css/index.css'))
});
```

Comment: Now I have an error  EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Step-Ham\src\css\index.css'

Comment: Use gulp-chmod like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43798562/gulp-sass-unable-to-override-already-existing-file

Comment: I tried to use that variant and now I have this  Error: watching src/scss/index.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
    at Gulp.watch (C:\Step-Ham\node_modules\gulp\index.js:31:11)
    at C:\Step-Ham\gulpfile.js:13:10
    at taskWrapper (C:\Step-Ham\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:402:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:415:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\Step-Ham\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)

Comment: Without "require('gulp-watch');"?

Comment: I had update my code, and I tried run it with 'require gulp' and without, but nothing work

Comment: Maybe I had including something not right, can you look into my repository?

Comment: You reverted the gulp.watch() code to the previous version. You have to use the one in my answer *and* gulp-chmod as in the link. I am updating my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I had tried to delete gulp-building of my project and download it with running again, all became fine, I didn't found reason about once gulp-watch didn't work 0__0 Thank you very much